# Finding/Predicting BotNet Generated Domains Without DGA Knowledge

Tags: ransomware, botnet

I will pose an academic perspective in my question, but I welcome any and every observation. So a botnet would generate 1000s of domain/day and an actual attacker will register a few, which will be used with a certain probability. Point is, given a dataset of say a million domains and without the knowledge of DGA (Domain Generation Algorithm), is there any technique/research available that predicts the likelihood of a domain being a bot generated one? I have my own few ideas to make one:

1. Exclude Dictionary Word Domains
2. Include Seeming Random/Garbage/Arbitrarily Large Domain Names
3. Cross Check DNS information for possible registration information etc.

Sadly, I couldn't find any standard research/text on this area. Any information would be helful.

Comment: The lazy approach would be to train a classifier with lists of known legitimate and fake domains. But there are plenty of legitimate uses for seemingly random domain names and plenty of possibility for a bot to use a dictionary based approach. You will have a lot of false positives/negatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of your three ideas are not applicable:

1. > Exclude Dictionary Word Domains

   There are DGAs that use dictionary word domains, for example [matsnu](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andrewaeva/DGA/master/dga_wordlists/matsnu.txt)
2. > Include Seeming Random/Garbage/Arbitrarily Large Domain Names

   There are absolutely legitimate domain names that have been generated by an DGA, especially in this time of "serverless" hosting with ephemeral domain names.
3. > Cross Check DNS information for possible registration information etc.

   There is not way to tell legitimate and illegitimate customers of domain registrars that offer anonymity.

There is however a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/andrewaeva/DGA) that collects outputs from various DGAs to try and use machine learning for recognition of plausible and probable malicious DGA generated domains.

Comment: So apart from that repository, technically there is no research in this area?

Comment: There is probably a lot of research in the area.